# Is it possible to use wildcards for queue permissions in WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: jms, message-queue, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

The embedded messaging server in WebSphere Liberty supports access control on queues. In the `server.xml`, the following structure can be added under the **messagingEngine** section:

```
<messagingSecurity>
       <role name="queueAccess">
          <group name="admin"></group>
          <queuePermission queueRef="myQueues.queue_1">
             <action>ALL</action>
          </queuePermission>
       </role>
</messagingSecurity>
```

This would grant the admin user access to the queue `myQueues.queue_1` but, if I want to grant access to multiple queues `myQueues.queue_1` to `myQueues.queue_n`, it seems I have to create a section per queue.

I have tried several wildcards, such as **myQueues*** or like a regexp **myQueues.*** - but no luck. I have been unable to find any documentation on the use of wildcards, so can someone confirm or deny whether wildcards are possible in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see (digged into the code of openliberty), there is no wildcard handler for it.

I know jboss uses this wildcard for jms security handling:

```
. (a single period) Denotes the space between words in a wildcard expression.
# (a pound or hash symbol) Matches any sequence of zero or more words.
* (an asterisk) Matches a single word.
```

Maybe something to hint for the liberty community ;)